magnolia webhook configuration not triggering
I want to integrate webhook with magnolia
I created a light module. Inside that module, I created a 'webhook' folder where I placed my YAML file and published page. However, my webhook is not being triggered.
name: webhook1new
url: https://webhook.site/f8416277-2da7-4811-a6e0-f5a652dca43f 
method: POST
queryParameters:
access_token: '2cf09447'
headers:
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
enabled: true
events:
  - name: contentPublished
    eventType: Published
    entity: Content   
  - name: contentUnpublished
    eventType: Unpublished
    entity: Content


You mention using a folder called "webhook", but the folder must be named "webhooks".
A tip: it is often helpful to look in the log to see if a definition was detected. Also have a look in the "Definitions" app. To see if it is registered or not.
Note that webhooks feature is only available on "DX Core". If you are using "Community edition" it will not be available.
